# want to populate a matrix with numbers in random positions and their frequency are given

Tags: java, matrix, random

I want to create a matrix with numbers in the range 0-2, the number of times each number appears in the matrix is given but their positions have to be random.

Comment: Its unclear what is the question?

Comment: what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the matrix M and initialize it with -1.
2. Have R, C as the number of Rows, Columns of the matrix.
3. Let C0 = count of 0s, C1 = count of 1s, C2 = count of 2s.

4.// Update 0s in the matrix

```
while(C0 > 0)
{
int row = get a Random number between 0, R
int col = get a Randome number between 0,C

if(M[row][col] == -1)
{
  M[row][col] = 0;
  C0--;
}
else
{
// Do not update this cell as a value has been put in it
}

}
```

5. Do the same thing for 1s
6. Do the same thing for 2s

Comment: this is not efficient if the random cell turns to be one that is already updated the process has to be repeated. When there are few cells in the matrix to be updated this will happen more often.

Comment: For Random assignment you will never be able to avoid collisions.

Comment: I can go over each position of the matrix assigning random numbers in the range 0-2 and decreasing the count of them. That's what I want to implement, I asked because my code has too many lines and I wanted to improve it, anyway I found a better way, thanks.